# Storage class in query builder

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have an ajax  request in JSON and I need to return a file path, to download a file.

I get the storage like this:

```
$attachments = $req->file('files')[$key][0]->storeAs('purchase', $filename);
```

I have symlinked the storage:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

In my controller I do the following:

```
 $dataAttachments = DB::table('purchase_requests_attachments AS a')
                    ->join('users AS b', 'a.id_usr_add', '=', 'b.id')
                    ->join('purchase_attachments_rules AS c', 'a.id_rule', '=', 'c.id')
                    ->select(DB::RAW(Storage::download('a.file', 'tituloteste')), 'a.id AS id', 'a.id_usr_add AS id_usr', 'b.full_name AS full_name', 'a.id_rule AS id_rule', 'c.description as description', 'a.file AS attachment', 'a.created_at AS created_at')->where('a.id_request', '=', $id_purchase)->get();
```

The raw doesn't work to return the path to request.
The raw method does not seem to return the correct path.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you copy this from your code or did you type it out? Because I don't think trying to access the `raw` method in uppercase will work for you. Try changing it from `RAW` to `raw`.

Also, if you want the url to the resource then you should do `Storage::url()`, not `Storage::download()`.

Comment: Hi i was paste. Now i change to DB::raw and Storage::url, my code now:
`->select(DB::raw(Storage::url('a.file')), 'a.id AS id', 'a.id_usr_add AS id_usr', 'b.full_name AS full_name', 'a.id_rule AS id_rule', 'c.description as description', 'a.file AS attachment', 'a.created_at AS created_at')->where('a.id_request', '=', $id_purchase)->get();
`

Show this error:
`SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"LINE 1: select /storage/a.file, "a"."id" as "id", "a"."id_usr_add"`